# ASP.NET MVC EF Securing Controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm having some troubles determining what is the best practice to secure routes in .NET using EF7 and MVC. I have my own table Roles (so I'm not using the AspNetRoles).

Is the correct approach to (in my Commoncontroller) make something according to this:

```
public class AuthorizeAllExceptAdmin : AuthorizeAttribute
{
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
    return !httpContext.User.IsInRole(Constants.ROLES_ADMINISTRATOR);
}
}
```

(this comming from: [ASP .NET MVC Securing a Controller/Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298110/asp-net-mvc-securing-a-controller-action)).

Or how is it done? I've trying to read up a little, but I couldn't really find a valid answer.

Also, the post above is a little bit old, so can I still use that?

Thank you

Comment: Which version of MVC are you using?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm actually using MVC6.

Answer (score -1):

You seems to be on the right track, see if this can help you,
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/288631/Secure-ASP-NET-MVC-applications#Create

Comment: Hi. Just posting links to external resources is not really wanted on StackOverflow (The url can become invalid, be outdated etc..) It's better to post a snippet or explain the solution.

Comment: Hmmn, I keep having troubles with even adding the [Authorize] filter to my controllers. They are not recognized (and even after adding a lot of namespaces, I can't seem to find the correct one).

Comment: Hey, can you look at this link if it's helpful to you: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464359/custom-authorizeattribute-in-asp-net-5-mvc-6)